# Which salsa ingredient makes it taste like dirt?

Tags: ingredient-selection, salsa

I suppose it could also be considered "earthy".

There is an ingredient that is often added to "authentic" salsas that often ends up making it taste too "earthy".

Which ingredient is it?
Is it cilantro?

Comment: People who don't like cilantro usually describe it as soapy, not earthy.

Comment: When I think of ingredients that taste like dirt, I think of baby corn ... but that wouldn't likely be in salsa.

Comment: What ever it is, it's not found in many commercial salsas. This has just been a question I've never found a direct answer to.

Comment: I think that non-commercial salsas usually taste "brighter" if anything. Where are you getting these salsas?

Comment: @sourd'oh : Every place doea their salsa different. Various 'Mexican' cafes and restaurants. It seems like the more *tradional* restaurants make their salsa that way. Newer restaurants and cafes tend to have 'brighter' tasting salsa, to steal a term from an above comment. :)

Comment: Could it be turmeric?

Comment: Are you sure they are pure salsas? Moles (including tomato based ones) will frequently include chocolate, which has an earthy flavor.

Comment: @rumtscho : Yea, it's normal salsa. Typically chunky and "fresh". Definitely not molè. Normally the salsas in question are pretty mild. Currently trying to decide on an answer... I'd never considered cumin or tomatillos as possibly suspects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My partner has a very sensitive "dirt-flavor" sense... One of the ingredients that may be found in salsa that often triggers it for her is cumin.

Comment: My dad has the same thing - hates anything with cumin in it because it tastes like dirt to him.

Comment: I love cumin, but my wife thinks it tastes like mud.

Comment: So weird, cumin has such a wonderful perfume and flavor. The only way it could taste like dirt is if you were using a tin that had been sitting in your spice rack too long, imho.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments pointed out, everyone does Salsa differently, but if you add chioptle pepper you will get a heated dark flavor. Also, depending on how you are charring your veggies, tomatillos can also do this - especially if roasted with their skins still on.